# What is the most Ruby-like way of generating every unique combination of 3 positive integers that add up to 100

Tags: ruby, function, combinations, permutation

Conditions:

```
a + b + c = 100
a,b,c positive integers or 0
```

Desired output:

```
[
  [0,0,100],
  [0,1,99 ],
  ... # all other permutations
  [99,1,0 ],
  [100,0,0]
]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd write:

```
(0..100).flat_map { |x| (0..100-x).map { |y| [x, y, 100-x-y] } }
#=> [[0, 0, 100], [0, 1, 99]], ..., [99, 1, 0], [100, 0, 0]]
```

Site note 1: this is a classical example where list-comprehensions shine (and even more if there were a condition somewhere). Since Ruby has no LC we have to do the typical conversion to OOP: *N-1* `flat_map`'s + *1* `map`. It would be awesome to have LCs in Ruby (check [this feature request](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5663)), Scala has proven that even a pure OOP language greatly benefits from this syntactic sugar (though I can understand prevention from the devs because of the implicit iterable protocol/method). On an imaginary Ruby that supported them you'd write:

```
[[x, y, 100-x-y] for x in 0..100 for y in 0..100-x] # imaginary Ruby
```

Side note 2: Imagine that you prefer a less memory-consuming solution (you probably don't need the whole array). A lazy solution with Ruby 2.0 requires just to add a couple of `[lazy][2]` proxies:

```
(0..100).lazy.flat_map { |x| (0..100-x).lazy.map { |y| [x, y, 100-x-y] } }
```

Side note 3: Just for completeness, in the line of @akuhn answer, another lazy solution using enumerators:

```
Enumerator.new do |e| 
  (0..100).each { |x| (0..100-x).each { |y| e.yield([x, y, 100-x-y]) } }
end
```

Comment: Not a bad approach, but I'd just generate all possible combinations of a, b, and c and do a `find_all` of combinations that add up to 100.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm your approach will do about 500,000 times as much work as tokland's.

Comment: @dbenhur yes, but that's work Ruby would do, not work I'd do!

Comment: My first solution was: "output=[];(0..100).to_a.each{|a|(0..100).to_a.each{|b|(0..100).to_a.each{|c|output<<[a,b,c]}}};output.select{|x|x.sum==100}"... but I prefer this one of Tokland's... it's much faster in benchmarking

Comment: I am now considering how one would write an efficient method that would take as arguments: - an integer specifying the number of integers (i.e. size of each array [a,b,c...,...,zzz]) - the desired total (100 here). But that may deserve another question.

Thanks for directing me to that Ruby feature request.

Comment: yeah, better a new question for that. It can be done with recursion, try it yourself, it is not too difficult.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution

```
for a in 0..100; for b in 0..100-a; p [a,b,100-a-b]; end; end
```

which I find reads almost like @tokland’s list comprehension. If you like to use the values further downstream rather than printing them, put the code in a generator method

```
def generate
  return enum_for(:generate) unless block_given?
  for a in 0..100
    for b in 0..100-a
      yield [a,b,100-a-b]
    end
  end
end
```

which is then used as in

```
generate { |a,b,c| puts [a,b,c] }
```

or as in

```
generate { |each| p each }
```

or as in

```
p generate.to_a
```

which all print all generated tuples.

Comment: Sometimes I use this Python-generator-like approach also, though it feels less functional (FP sense). Anyway, instead of inserting a `to_enum` guard (which core Ruby methods do to be more versatile), you can also decide to return always an enumerator, which makes sense for potentially large outputs: `Enumerator.new { |yielder| ... yielder.yield x }`.

Comment: @tokland what's the difference between `to_enum` and an enumerator? Just a matter of style, or is there an implementation difference? I'd figure they both use fibers for coroutines.

Comment: @tokland the question was about "Ruby-style" not a strictly "functional-programming style" :)

Comment: There is no difference, but you are not forced to write a separate method with a Enumerator block. I know it was not a FP question, it was just a personal remark (meaning that I tend to favour functional solutions whenever possible).

Comment: Gotcha. // Yes, not having to write a method can come in handy at times.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say the most Ruby-ish way (which is not by any means the most efficient way) is this:

```
(0..100).to_a.repeated_permutation(3).find_all{|triplet|triplet.inject(:+)==100}
```

The only non-transparent part of this chain is the `to_a`, which converts the range object given by (0..100) to an array (ranges are lazy, which doesn't work with `repeated_permutation`).

Comment: I like it! While it does seem most Ruby-ish (i.e. magic, terse, and natural language-ish), I will be accepting @tokland's answer, in this instance. I am open to argument, though.

Comment: No doubt this is simpler to understand (I wouldn't say more Ruby-sh, why is that?), and if I knew that N were always small, I'd probably go for it. However, from a computational point of view converting a O(n^2) problem into a O(n^3) is a bit dubious to say the least. Increase N a little bit and you'll run into big trouble.

Comment: This is nice, but it doesn't find all the combinations. It includes `[0,0,100]`, but not `[100,0,0]`, for instance.

Comment: @Adam: Good point; I misread the spec.  I'll change `repeated_combination` to `repeated_permutation`.